# How to get column value without using in GROUP BY clause

Tags: select, sql-server-2012, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to update the VHMAIN table with latest time which retrieved from VHSTATUS table. I wrote the query like below

```
select a.vehi_id,a.statustime,a.vhstatus,max(b.statustime) 
newstatustime,b.vhstatus newstatus
from vhmain a inner join vhstatus b on a.vehi_id=b.vehi_id2 
group by a.vehi_id,a.statustime,a.vhstatus having 
a.statustime<>max(b.statustime)
```

**I'm getting error as**

> Column 'vhstatus.vhstatus' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I add 'vhstatus.vhstatus' in GROUP BY clause whole data will be wrong

Please suggest me the query

**Edit:** Tables and expected result data

> ```
> VHMAIN
> vehi_id   statustime  vhstatus
> 38        2004-03-08      9
>
> VHSTATUS
> vehi_id2  statustime  vhstatus
> 38        2004-03-11  55  
> 38        2004-03-08  55  
> 38        2004-03-08  9
>
> Expected result
> vehi_id   statustime  vhstatus    newstatustime newstatus
> 38        2004-03-08  9            2004-03-11     55
> ```

Comment: Please, add the structure of the tables involved. Some sample data will not hurt either.

Comment: Where is the update statement?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow I guess George is trying to select the correct values first to make sure the update will actually update the intended records.

Comment: @LajosArpad: edited with sample structure of tables.

Comment: I have added an answer based on the structure you have, but note that it is untested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Have you tried making nested query?

eg:

```
select tbl.*, department.Name
from department 
  inner join (
     select departmentId, COUNT(*) cnt
     from employees
     group by departmentId 
) AS tbl on tbl.departmentId = department.Id
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. I got an idea

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
update VHMAIN
set VHMAIN.vhstatus = VHSTATUS.vhstatus
from VHMAIN
inner join VHSTATUS
on VHMAIN.vehi_id = VHSTATUS.vehi_id2
where VHSTATUS.statustime = (select top 1 vhs.statustime
                             from VHSTATUS.statustime vhs
                             where vhs.vehi_id2 = VHSTATUS.vehi_id2
                             order by vhs.statustime desc);
```

The untested code above will `select` the item with the most recent `statustime` from `VHSTATUS` and check it against the `statustime` in the outer command so you find exactly the item you are searching for, then `update` `VHMAIN` to its `vhstatus`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  tbl.*,x.vhstatus from vhstatus x inner join (select 
a.vehi_id,a.statustime,a.vhstatus,max(b.statustime) newstatustime from vhmain a
inner join vhstatus b on a.vehi_id=b.vehi_id2 group by 
a.vehi_id,a.statustime,a.vhstatus  having max(a.statustime) 
<>max(b.statustime)) tbl on tbl.newstatustime=x.statustime and 
tbl.vehi_id=x.vehi_id2  order by tbl.vehi_id
```